# How can I obtain OSHA 300 nursing home data?

Tags: labor

I am trying to obtain OSHA 300 form data submitted by nursing homes.  Is this data available for download from the Department of Labor?

Comment: I will ask my OSHA colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

The Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA) collected work-related injury and illness data from employers within specific industry (including nursing homes) and employment size specifications from 1996 through 2011. These data are available at http://www.osha.gov/pls/odi/establishment_search.html  This data collection is called the OSHA Data Initiative or ODI. The data provided is used by OSHA to calculate establishment specific injury and illness incidence rates. This searchable database contains a table with the name, address, industry, and associated Total Case Rate (TCR), Days Away, Restricted, and Transfer (DART) case rate, and the Days Away From Work (DAFWII) case rate for the establishments that provided OSHA with valid data for calendar years 1996 through 2011. In addition, data from 2002 through 2011 is also available in downloadable txt files located on this web page.  The survey was discontinued after the collection of reference year 2011 data.

The Bureau of Labor Statistics publishes occupational injury and illness counts and rates, including data on case and demographic characteristics.  These data are at the aggregate industry level, rather than the establishment level.  Please visit the BLS website at http://www.bls.gov/iif/home.htm to download their injury and illness statistics.  If you would rather use an API to access the injury and illness data, please see http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/injuries-and-illness/ for our documentation for the API endpoint.  Information on using our API can be found at http://developer.dol.gov/.

Comment: Thank you--we require access to our data for 2013 onward that has not been aggregated so that we may create KPI metrics.  We are a chain of 40 skilled nursing facilities in the northeast U.S. and each facility is required to fill out and submit an OSHA 300 report yearly.  As far as I know, the OSHA 300 form is a PDF document that contains editable data input fields.  I find it a little annoying that OSHA will not permit access to our own data.  Not sure if these PDFs are getting saved by each facility.  Even if they are, it is difficult to extract data from PDFs, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: ..in the best of all possible worlds, it would help if we could generate our own DART scores on a monthly, rather than yearly, basis.